# Synology DS213 - Java compiler

Tags: javac, synology

Tried to run Jenkins on Synology but always fail with java compile. Though "javac" has been supplied it always fails with "file or directory not found". Even directly calling from console (cd /bin; javac) gives this error. (jdk has been downloaded from oracle as 32 bit ARM jdk).
Is there a "javac" out there which can be run on Synology DS213?

Comment: Have you tried `cd /bin; ./javac`? Of course, that's assuming the compiler is in `/bin`.

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you using a product primarily meant as a file server to run CI pipelines?

Comment: I want to run java there. For me it looks natural to deploy it also there. Jenkins does fine with the GIT part but compiling fails.
Yes, I used the correct path. I know it is in the jdk/bin path and tried to execute it. The "java"-cmd is fine while the "javac"-cmd fails. Thought the message is sort of strange - but the only explanation I can think of is that the "javac"-code is not compiled for my " Feroceon 88FR131 rev 1 (v5l)".

Comment: Why shouldn't I use the DS213 for this? It has low power consumption and runs fine for java (up to java 8 - for higher versions I did not find embedded jres. Oracle has dropped the support). I'm running tomcat here and see no reason not to run jenkins